# Refactorizando con .map()

Tags: javascript

Estoy  intentando refactorizar una funcion que filtra ciudades y la funcion inicial esta escrita de esta manera:

```
Listado.prototype.obtenerUbicaciones = function() {
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.restaurantes.length; i++) {
        c.push(this.restaurantes[i].ubicacion);
    }
    return (this.noRepeat(ciudadFiltrada)).sort();
}
```

El problema esta en que lo estoy intentando refactorizar utilizando map() y no me salta ningun error, pero tampoco funciona de acuerdo a lo necesario. Lo estoy implementando asi:

```
Listado.prototype.obtenerUbicaciones = function() {
    var ciudades = [];
    var ciudadFiltrada = ciudades.map(function(ciudad{
        return ciudad;
    });
    return (this.noRepeat(ciudadFiltrada)).sort();
}
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lo mejor es esto: puedes utilizar `map()` en lugar del bucle for. También puedes utilizar de la misma manera `forEach()`

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    Listado.prototype.obtenerUbicaciones = function() {
        var c = [];
        /*
        for (var i = 0; i < this.restaurantes.length; i++) {
            c.push(this.restaurantes[i].ubicacion);
        }
        */
        this.restaurantes.map(r =>{c.push(r.ubicacion)})

        return (this.noRepeat(ciudadFiltrada)).sort();
    }
```

Comment: Mil gracias enxaneta, me puedes explicar la "r" a que vendria definida?

Comment: La `r` sería el equivalente de `this.restaurantes[i]` el bucle for comentado. Es una variable que representa el restaurante y le puedes dar otro nombre si quieres. A mi me gustan los nombres cortos de variables porque son menos verbosos.